# How to display static banner on top of Product page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is the image of what I am trying to achieve
[image: static banner of product page]

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also manage with static block, create one static and put image or content there and this static block call on your theme product view file :

```
app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Open above file and past this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

above

```
<div class="product-view">
```

this div so exectly you get your satic block content as you need.

Now, this solution is for every product show same content , but if you need for some product show this banner or content then you need to put product id condition so you show banner specific product.

hope it help of you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i want to enable banner on products in specific category. Other categories products will too have banner but it will be a different banner.

Comment: You mean, you  want to set category wise banner, if set banner in category then this banner show on every product page of this category right???

Comment: For that you want to add one attribute (textarea, image etc.) in category and add content on it and this content set on product view page using current category id collection.

Comment: Adding attribute in category?  Pls can you send me a link explaining how to do that?. Or pls can you explain your answer more in detail pls.

Comment: Ok sure, Now you need to set value in attribute and then after this attribute value call in Product view page, product page link i have mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

try this extension: https://amasty.com/promo-banners.html

review this tutorial: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/banners-anywhere-with-magento-widget-instances/